# What's the correct pronunciation of BIOS (Basic Input/Output System)?

Tags: pronunciation, acronyms

What's the correct pronunciation of [BIOS](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/BIOS-basic-input-output-system) (Basic Input/Output System)?

1. **[ˈbaɪɒs]**, like in [growth-promoting substance present in yeast](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/19250?BIOS)
2. or **['bɪɒs]**, thus respecting the meaning of the acronym - [input], not [aɪnput]
3. or something else?

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS) states only the first pronunciation, but I have heard both quite often.

**I am specifically interested if the knowledge of the meaning of the acronym may influence its pronunciation.** Particularly Input which pronunciation starts with [i] and not with [ai].

N.B. The acronym is always **pronounced as a word** in the IT world, it's never spelled letter-by-letter (like "USA").

Comment: You pronounce it like a word

Comment: I do know it's pronounced like a word! But how? :)

Comment: Rhymes with "bayou": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GAuZtwVnRWo

Comment: @HonzaZidek 'BY-oss' | | "BI-oss" | | "BYE-os"

Comment: So never bee-oss or be-oss? That's something which would sound *also* OK to me knowing that the "I" word of the acronym is pronounced with [i] and not with [ai] at the beginning.

Comment: /'bɪɒs/ is not even pronounceable (at least not for an American English speaker) because the phoneme /ɪ/ can only occur before a consonant.

Comment: I've only ever heard it pronounced "buy-aus" or "buy-yoss" (same thing, just different attempts at spelling).  I've been in the biz since 1972, worked for IBM for much of that time.

Comment: @sumelic: please feel free to fix my question accordingly - I am not very familiar with IPA, what I meant was the sound like in *bee* or at the beginning of *input*.

Comment: I pronounce it BYE-OhS  where the *S* in OhS is a hard S, as if you stopped saying "Oh so nice" right after sounding the *s*.

Comment: Corrected earlier comment: bee is pronounced /bi/ with /i/; input is pronounced /ˈɪnˌpʊt/ (or [ˈɪmˌpʊt]) with /ɪ/. The difference between /i/ and /ɪ/ is the sole factor distinguishing words like "sheet" /ʃit/ from "shit" /ʃɪt/, or "beach" /bitʃ/ from "bitch" /bɪtʃ/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The computing term *BIOS*, as I have heard it in the U.S., in commonly pronounced  /ˈbaɪɔs/ or /'baɪoʊs/ — *i* as in *fly* (not *bee*) and *s* as in *moose* (not *muse*) if that is a help. The only people I know who pronounce the first syllable as /bɪ/ or /bi/ are non-native speakers.

---

The orthography and pronunciation of an acronym are contrived, as with most any neologism. The pronunciation of an acronym may have **no relation** to the pronunciation of its constituents— I might consider thinking so to be a variation of the [etymological fallacy](http://www.logicallyfallacious.com/index.php/logical-fallacies/81-etymological-fallacy).

Consider three common acronyms:

- PIN (Personal Identification Number) – as /pɪn/, like the word *pin*, despite the pronunciation of *identification*
- scuba (self-contained underwater breathing apparatus)  – as /'skuːbə/, despite *underwater*
- NATO (North Atlantic Treaty Organization) — /'neɪtoʊ/, despite *Atlantic*

Like so many other things in English, you cannot always predict the pronounciation from the spelling and vice versa. The United States Pacific Command, *PACOM*, is pronounced */'peɪkɒm/*, not */pə'kɒm/* as might be suggested by *Pacific* or even */'pækɒm/* as might be suggested by *Pac-Man*. And while the *FTSE 100* may be the *footsy one hundred* , the *DJIA* has no acronymic name; it's the *Dow Jones* or the *Dow 30*.

Someone who coins an acronym may well choose which letters to use in order to create a word, or to force it to conform to an existing one. Thus, the North American Aerospace Defense Command is *NORAD*, not *NAADC*, and the Uniting and Strengthening America by Providing Appropriate Tools Required to Intercept and Obstruct Terrorism Act of 2001 gained its ridiculous moniker so that it could be referred to as [USA PATRIOT](http://www.justice.gov/archive/ll/highlights.htm). For yet another military example, there's no inherent reason why *[HMMWV](http://www.amgeneral.com/vehicles/hmmwv/)* is pronounced as *humvee* other than that some Army official probably said it that way when the contract was being bid. In another universe it might have been a *home-mauve* or *him-wave* or something else entirely.

Still, the "official" way is not necessarily what gains currency in the population at large. Consider the longstanding discussion over [how to pronounce *Linux*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5IfHm6R5le0)— some say */lɪnʊks/* and others */lɪnəks/*, but in the earliest interview I ever heard with Linus Torvalds— perhaps from a time when his English was less practiced— it sounded distinctly like */linuks/* to me.

Answer (score 4):

If you want the US pronunciation, simply go to Youtube and search for bios, e.g. [Updating Gigabyte Motherboard BIOS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lJ_hWeg_wF0)

Note that final vowel in particular will vary according to region. UK pronunciation will be different from US for example.

However, if we ignore that then definitely in the UK I have only heard the [ˈbaɪɒs] version.

---

**Note**

For those unfamiliar with IPA, it sounds like 'BY-oss' (and not like 'BEE-oss')

---

**Edit**

> I am specifically interested if the knowledge of the meaning of the
>   acronym may influence its pronunciation. Particularly Input which
>   pronunciation starts with [i] and not with [ai].

The answer to that is that there is no such rule. Of course the pronunciation could be the same by coincidence.

Comment: I've also heard it with a long O, /BY-ohss/

Comment: @Barmar, Thanks: I've added to my answer. See the link to youtube.

Answer (score 3):

I am in IT, and have always heard it pronounced either like "Bias" by english speakers, or sometimes more like "Buy-yoss".